# Forming triangles out of points with x and y coordinates using a linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a linkedList that contains information about a point: It's color, its x and y coordinate.

```
Color: Red  | X coordinate: 5   |  Y coordinate: 7
Color: Blue  | X coordinate: 6   |  Y coordinate: 5
Color: Red  | X coordinate: 2   |  Y coordinate: 4
Color: Blue  | X coordinate: 3   |  Y coordinate: 0
Color: Red  | X coordinate: 0   |  Y coordinate: 0
Color: Blue  | X coordinate: 0   |  Y coordinate: 5
Color: Yellow  | X coordinate: 1   |  Y coordinate: 4
Color: Yellow  | X coordinate: 2   |  Y coordinate: 3
Color: Yellow  | X coordinate: 1   |  Y coordinate: 1
```

I need to find form a triangle out of matching colors and find its perimeter. How would i go about doing this?

My final output should be:

```
Color: Red      |   Perimter: {}    |
Color: Blue     |   Perimeter: {}   |
Color: Yellow   |   Perimeter: {}   |
```

Comment: just want to check with your, the perimeter is calculated by how? because x, y just place the point. The perimeter is calculated from sum of your length, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with method that calculates length of poligonal chain:

```
private static double CalculatePerimeter(List<(int x, int y)> points)
{
    if (points.Count < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("Should be at least two points", "points");

    // for triangles
    // if (points.Count != 3)
    //    throw new ArgumentException("Triangle should have only three points", "points");

    var lastPoint = points[0];
    var perimeter = 0.0;
    for (var i = 1; i < points.Count; ++i)
    {
        var currentPoint = points[i];
        perimeter += Math.Sqrt(
            Math.Pow(currentPoint.x - lastPoint.x, 2) +
            Math.Pow(currentPoint.y - lastPoint.y, 2));

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    return perimeter;
}
```

Now you need to group your points by color and call `CalculatePerimeter` on all points in each group:

```
var input = new[]
{
    new {color = "Red", X = 5, Y = 7},
    new {color = "Blue", X = 6, Y = 5},
    new {color = "Red", X = 2, Y = 4},
    new {color = "Blue", X = 3, Y = 0},
    new {color = "Red", X = 0, Y = 0},
    new {color = "Blue", X = 0, Y = 5},
    new {color = "Yellow", X = 1, Y = 4},
    new {color = "Yellow", X = 2, Y = 3},
    new {color = "Yellow", X = 1, Y = 1},
};

var result = input
    .GroupBy(x => x.color)
    .Select(g => new {color = g.Key, perimeter = CalculatePerimeter(g.Select(p => (x : p.X, y: p.Y)).ToList())});

foreach (var triangle in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"Triangle color {triangle.color}, perimeter {triangle.perimeter}");
```

Output will be:

> Triangle color Red, perimeter 8,71477664211886
>   Triangle color Blue, perimeter 11,6619037896906
>   Triangle color Yellow, perimeter 3,65028153987288

Comment: If you supply a list with 2 points, it will throw an exception saying "Should be at least two points" (which doesn't make sense). Maybe the condition should have been `points.Count < 2`? (and the type could be more specific, e.g. `ArgumentException`)

Comment: @Ghost4Man thank you very much. It actually was a bug I've missed because only test this code with OP input. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Point> points = new List<Point>() {
                new Point() { Color = "Red", X = 5, Y = 7},
                new Point() { Color = "Blue", X = 6, Y = 5},
                new Point() { Color = "Red", X = 2, Y = 4},
                new Point() { Color = "Blue", X = 3, Y = 0},
                new Point() { Color = "Red", X = 0, Y = 0},
                new Point() { Color = "Blue", X = 0, Y = 5},
                new Point() { Color = "Yellow", X = 1, Y = 4},
                new Point() { Color = "Yellow", X = 2, Y = 3},
                new Point() { Color = "Yellow", X = 1, Y = 1}
            };

            //create link list
            LinkedList<Point> list = new LinkedList<Point>();
            foreach (Point point in points)
            {
                list.AddLast(point);
            }

            var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.Color).Select(x => new { color = x.Key, perimeter = x.Select(y => new { X = y.X, Y = y.Y }).ToList() }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Point
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }


}
```